# PIC32MX220F032D ADC on PortB

Tags: c, pic

I have been working with Olimex Board PIC32-PINGUINO-MX220.

While I was trying to configure the ADC, I could see that the 
`#define OpenADC10` has a reference to `mPORTBSetPinsAnalogIn` on the 4th parameter, which means that, using this `#define`, I can only configure Analog Channels defined on Port B, right?

If this is true, why there is no mention to that on the PIC32 Peripheral Libraries for
MPLAB C32 Compiler from Microchip?

Answer (score 0):

According this [documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/32bitPeripheralLibraryGuide.pdf) (page 109) that **was** mentioned in there.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ruslan Thanks for your reply, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: Hi Ruslan Thanks for your reply, but this does not answer my question. Microchip should warn that the 4th parameter regards only to port B, otherwise, the purpose on creating a library to help unexperienced programmers is useless, because, if programmers set a port other than port b channel on the 4th parameter, the ADC will simply not work on that port, which will make thinks more confuse and frustrating.

Comment: Other problem with the file adc10.h is that it creates defines like the next one. #define SKIP_SCAN_AN0             (1 << _AD1CSSL_CSSL0_POSITION)       /*AN0 enable for Input Scan */
The name of the define is correct but the comment is wrong. In fact, when using this define on the 5th parameter, the programmer wants to skip that analog input, not enable it for input scan, as stated in the comment.

Comment: That's correct, I think you could write to Microchip about that. They might accept your comments and improve it. This would be little but great improvement.